# Aerospark build (and running with PySpark)

Tags: apache-spark, aerospike

I am having trouble building the Aerospark connector @ https://github.com/aerospike/aerospark

I have created fresh Ubuntu box, installed JDK, SBT, Maven, Scala 2.10, and then followed the steps at the github page above. During the build i get this error and I am not sure which is the most direct way to build this properly....

```
[error] 1 error was encountered during merge 
java.lang.RuntimeException: deduplicate: different file contents found in 
the     following: /opt/astools/aerospark/lib/aerospike-helper-java-
1.0.6.jar:META-INF/maven/com.aerospike/aerospike-client/pom.xml
/root/.m2/repository/com/aerospike/aerospike-helper-java/1.0.6/aerospike-
helper-java-1.0.6.jar:META-INF/maven/com.aerospike/aerospike-client/pom.xml
/root/.ivy2/cache/com.aerospike/aerospike-client/jars/aerospike-client
3.3.1.jar:META-INF/maven/com.aerospike/aerospike-client/pom.xml
```

Are there any updated instructions for building this - the git link in the instructions seems outdated incidentally.

As an aside, has anyone tried this with PySpark?

Answer (score 3):

There was an issue with the build file which affected ubuntu. Can you pull the latest changes and go through the build process again?

Comment: Looks good - it builds fine and having listed it among the extra_jars it appears I can use it happily from PySpark. Thank you kindly!